# How to shape the weight matrices of RNNcells?

Tags: tensorflow, networking, recurrent-neural-network

Currently, I am only able to construct the weight matrices `hidden->output prediction` and `bias->output`.

The other matrices in the model, `input->hidden`, and `hidden->hidden`, are built deep within TensorFlow and I do not currently know how to define these when building my cell.

For instance, I would like to have my `input->hidden` weight matrix be a diagonal matrix, with off-diagonals set to zero.

Is there any way I can constrain them the way I want without putting the constraints in the cost function or updating the weights at every iteration?

Some of the contraints I want to implement are hard ones, hence it could significantly slow the learning. Changing the weights at each iteration to satisfy my contraints (e.g. off-diagonals to zero) seems also computationally inefficient. Any workaround or incoming features I should look for?